# Qt: Accessing C++ objects from QML by dot notation

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I want to access the C++ classes of my App from QML by dot notation with the use of square brackets, for example:

```
myapp.object1.child_object2["key1"].grandchild_object1.property56
myapp.object2.child_object8[291045].grandchild_object4.property14
```

I would like to be able to bind these (C++) objects to QML properties or to use them in Javascript code. What would be a fast and proper way to do this?

For example, lets say that MyApp has a Users object, which is a QAbstractItemModel class and it has a QMap() of users. Each entry in this QMap has an email address as a key, and a User() object which contains user properties, like email, name, etc...  So, the dot notation in this case would be:

```
myapp.users["johnsmith@domain.com"].name
myapp.users["johnsmith@domain.com"].password
```

Later, I would make it more complicated, adding a second level of hierarchy with a QMap() object for JohnSmith's tasks for example:

```
myapp.users["johnsmith@domain.com"].tasks[1].task_name
myapp.users["johnsmith@domain.com"].tasks[2].task_name
```

What mechanism should I use to expose my C++ objects in a ***HIERARCHICAL*** dot notation form ? I understand how PROPERTY macro works in Qt , but how to make it so that it could work for hierarchical dot notations ? Should I be using additional methods in my subclass of QAbstractItemModel class or should I overload the [] operator ? Is this possible (at all) to overload [] operator in QML engine? And, last question, if hierarchical dot notation in Qt is not possible at this time, would it be difficult to achieve by modifying the sources?

This is my source code, so far:

```
// File: main.cpp

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "myapp.h"
#include "users.h"
#include "user.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyApp>("com.myapp",1,0,"MyApp");
    qmlRegisterType<Users>("com.myapp.users",1,0,"Users");
    qmlRegisterType<User>("com.myapp.user",1,0,"User");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*MyApp class*.
Header:

```
//File: myapp.h


#ifndef MYAPP_H
#define MYAPP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include "users.h"

class MyApp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Users *users READ get_users WRITE set_users NOTIFY usersChanged);
private:
    Users               m_users;
public:
    explicit MyApp(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE Users *get_users();
    void set_users(Users *data);
signals:
    void usersChanged();
};
#endif // MYAPP_H
```

C source:

```
//File: myapp.cpp

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "myapp.h"
#include "users.h"
#include "user.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyApp>("com.myapp",1,0,"MyApp");
    qmlRegisterType<Users>("com.myapp.users",1,0,"Users");
    qmlRegisterType<User>("com.myapp.user",1,0,"User");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*Users file*.
Header:

```
//File: users.h

#ifndef USERS_H
#define USERS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QMap>
#include "user.h"

class Users : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    enum UserRoles {
        EmailRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        NameRole,
        PasswordRole
    };
private:
    QMap<QString,User*>         users_map;
public:
    explicit Users(QAbstractItemModel *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QModelIndex index(int row, int column,const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
signals:

public slots:
};    
#endif // USERS_H
```

Source:

```
//File: users.cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include "users.h"

Users::Users(QAbstractItemModel *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    User *u;
    u=new User();
    u->set_email("johnsmith@domain.com");
    u->set_name("John Smith");
    u->set_password("123");
    users_map.insert(u->get_email(),u);
    u=new User();
    u->set_email("juliepage@domain.com");
    u->set_name("Julie Page");
    u->set_password("321");
    users_map.insert(u->get_email(),u);
}
QModelIndex Users::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const {
    return QModelIndex();
}
QModelIndex Users::index(int row, int column,const QModelIndex &parent) const {

    QList <QString> qlist;
    qlist=users_map.keys();
    if (row>=qlist.size()) return QModelIndex();
    User *user=users_map[qlist.at(row)];
    return createIndex(row,column,user);
}
int Users::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return users_map.size();
}
int Users::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return 1;
}
QVariant Users::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    int row_num;

    row_num=index.row();
    if (role==EmailRole) {
        QList <QString> qlist;
        qlist=users_map.keys();
        if (row_num>=qlist.size()) return (QVariant());
        return QVariant(qlist.at(row_num));
    }
    if (role==NameRole) {
        QList <QString> qlist;
        qlist=users_map.keys();
        if (row_num>=qlist.size()) return (QVariant());
        User *user=users_map.value(qlist.at(row_num));
        return QVariant(user->get_name());
     }
    if (role==PasswordRole) {
        QList <QString> qlist;
        qlist=users_map.keys();
        if (row_num>=qlist.size()) return (QVariant());
        User *user=users_map[qlist.at(row_num)];
        return QVariant(user->get_password());
    }
    if (role==Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return(QVariant());
    }
    return (QVariant());
}
QHash<int, QByteArray> Users::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[EmailRole] = "email";
    roles[NameRole] = "name";
    roles[PasswordRole] = "password";
    return roles;
}
```

*User file*.
Header:

```
//File user.h
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <QObject>

class User : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString email READ get_email WRITE set_email NOTIFY emailChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ get_name WRITE set_name NOTIFY nameChanged);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ get_password WRITE set_password NOTIFY passwordChanged);
private:
    QString             email;
    QString             name;
    QString             password;
public:
    explicit User(QObject *parent = 0);
    const QString get_email();
    void set_email(QString data);
    const QString get_name();
    void set_name(QString data);
    const QString get_password();
    void set_password(QString data);
signals:
    void emailChanged();
    void nameChanged();
    void passwordChanged();
};
#endif // USER_H
```

Source:

```
//File: user.cpp

#include "user.h"

User::User(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
const QString User::get_email() {
    return email;
}
void User::set_email(QString data) {
    if (email!=data) {
        email=data;
        emit emailChanged();
    }
}
const QString User::get_name() {
    return name;
}
void User::set_name(QString data) {
    if (name!=data) {
        name=data;
        emit nameChanged();
    }
}
const QString User::get_password() {
    return password;
}
void User::set_password(QString data) {
    if (password!=data) {
        password=data;
        emit passwordChanged();
    }
}
```

QML file.

```
//File: main.qml

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

import com.myapp 1.0;
import com.myapp.users 1.0;
import com.myapp.user 1.0;

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true; width:640; height: 480;
    MyApp {
        id:myapp
    }
    ListView {
        model: myapp.users
        width: 300; height: 300
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            Text {
                text: model.email
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var users=myapp.users;
        var user=users["johnsmith@domain.com"];
        console.log("users object=" + users);
        console.log("user object=" + user);
        console.log("user's name="+user.name);
    }
}
```

Project file.
    //File: QML1.pro

```
QT += qml quick

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myapp.cpp \
    users.cpp \
    user.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    myapp.h \
    users.h \
    user.h
```

And the debug output, when I run the program:

```
qml: users object=Users(0x15cd1b0)
qml: user object=undefined
qrc:/main.qml:28: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

As you can see, I can't pass beyond the [] square bracket point, the `User` object is not being retrieved by QML.

Comment: Holy wall of text!!! When asking questions try to present your problem with the minimal amount of code, just a trivial example to reproduce the problem, not you entire production code, have mercy for the people trying to help out. And **NO** - you can't overload operators in QML, there is no operator overloading in JS, use slot or invokable functions if you want to access the functionality from QML.

Comment: @ddriver, heheh, this is not the production code, its a sample, the production code is >25k lines. Too bad, would be a nice feature to overload the [] operator. Maybe var somevar=object.method().submethod().subsubmethod() will work ?

Comment: Yes it will, provided that all the objects are either `QObject` derived or have meta generated via `Q_GADGET` and the members are invokable functions or properties. QML must know of that stuff, and that knowledge comes from the generation of meta information. BTW most of the stuff in your code is totally irrelevant to the subject. This is not helping anyone and therefore is not a good example.

Comment: @ddriver, but I had to copy Users.cpp and User.cpp because otherwise you wouldn't understand how exactly my objects are linked one to another. And other files were just added to make it a 100% compilable example.

Comment: You could have reproduced the problem in like 20 lines of code easy. Also, when providing such trivial examples, it is preferable to implement  the functions on the spot rather than split declarations and definitions so people can see what's going on at a glance rather than scrolling around.

Comment: ok, I understand, next time it will be shorter

Comment: Shortness is not key, conciseness is, be brief but comprehensive. Aim for a high substance to length ratio. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use operators for your C++ objects from QML, you need to use functions if you want access from QML. If you already have an object with operators, you can write function wrappers which call the operators.

The dot syntax will work as long as QML knows of the objects, in order words, it requires to have meta information generated for them. Therefore objects must be `QObject` derived, or using `Q_GADGET` and exposed as `Q_INVOKABLE` functions or `Q_PROPERTY`.

In which case instead of:

```
myapp.object1.child_object2["key1"].grandchild_object1.property56
```

you will

```
//    prop    prop          invokable   prop               prop
myapp.object1.child_object2.get("key1").grandchild_object1.property56
```

or if you implement sub-objects via accessor functions:

```
myapp.object1().child_object2().get("key1").grandchild_object1().property56
```

---

UPDATE:

Note that for a properly implemented `QQmlListProperty` you can use the `[]` operator, but only for index access. And you can't do it directly from the object, you have to do it from the object's list property, for example `object.listProperty[index]`. I noticed that even though you include `QQmlListProperty` in your code, it isn't really implemented.

So if you implement tasks as a `QQmlListProperty` of `User` then you could do something like this:

```
myapp.users.get("johnsmith@domain.com").tasks[1].task_name
```

Just make sure you don't go out of bounds. You also have `tasks.length` to avoid that.

I don't know exactly how this is implemented, but `QQmlListProperty` itself and associated types don't implement the `[]` operator. My guess is this is implemented someone on the QML engine level, and likely not as a part of a public API or directly available for use, which is quite typical for Qt internals.

Comment: thanks! I think via accessor functions it can look nicer, a bit more readable, if accessor functions are designed for QML

Comment: Properties *can* have notification, if a property changes, any code bound to it will automatically reevaluate. Therefore properties are a little more verbose too. If you don't need that invokable functions are the way to go. You can however use properties without notifications, and you don't even need to implement the accessor functions, you can use `MEMBER` properties for aggregated sub-objects which is very fast and clean. It is basically `Q_PROPERTY(Type subObject MEMBER someSubObject)`. then you can save on the `()` and implementing the actual accessors.

Comment: If I implement QQmlListProperty it would be myapp.users["johnsmith@domain.com"].tasks[1].task_name , right? Without the "get()" method, correct ? (because you are still using functions in your example)

Comment: No, you still need the `get()` method to use the string key. The `[]` will only work for integer indices.

Comment: I thought of QQmlListProperty and I included the header but then I thought it would be slow, because every time it is accessed, a QList will be returned, so ... if you have a list of 100 elements, that would be very inefficient, or wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it is OK. But you shouldn't use it unless you really need to. And you only need to if you are "filling" lists with declarative QML code. If all your stuff comes from C++ you don't need it.